# “Partition is below target replica or instance count” with stateful services on Service Fabric Local Cluster

Tags: azure, service-fabric-stateful, azure-service-fabric

Whenever I deploy any project on my local cluster (Even following simple Service Fabric tutorials online) I get the following message:

> System application is unhealthy.
>
> Unhealthy services: 100% (1/1), ServiceType='EventStoreServiceType', MaxPercentUnhealthyServices=0%.
>
> Unhealthy service: ServiceName='fabric:/System/EventStoreService', AggregatedHealthState='Error'.
>
> Unhealthy partitions: 100% (1/1), MaxPercentUnhealthyPartitionsPerService=0%.
>
> Unhealthy partition: PartitionId='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000009000', AggregatedHealthState='Error'.
>
> Error event: SourceId='System.FM', Property='State'. Partition is below target replica or instance count.

Even though I have more than 120GBs of disk space

Comment: How many nodes are in your cluster? Can you check whether all system services are healthy? Have you tried to create an empty Service Fabric project and deploy it to local cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue had something to do with my C drive, when I created a new drive with more than 10GBs space and located the cluster to that new drive the issue was solved.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue while trying to debug Service Fabric Application. When I published to local node there was no problem but had the same exact error when trying to run it in Debug mode.

**Solution:**

Go to Service Fabric project properties by right-clicking the Service Fabric Project (the one with Service Fabric Icon) -> **Properties  -> Application Debug Mode** and set it to **Remove Application**.
By default it is set to **Refresh Application** and the description says that it

*'refreshes the application with new binaries without redeploying the application'*

My colleague didn't have any issue with that setting but we succesfully solved that on couple of machines, so it's worth trying.

Answer (score 1):

Deploy an [amount of replicas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-concepts-partitioning) that is equal to or less than the amount of nodes in your cluster.
So, if you're running a single node [dev cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-with-a-local-cluster#one-node-and-five-node-cluster-mode), deploy a single replica. If you want to deploy more, you'll need to use the 5 node dev cluster.

Comment: hi loekD, I am confused that why the amount of replicas can't exceed the amount of nodes in cluster. in the doc you shared in the answer above, I can see 5 nodes with 10 partitions of stateful service, and each partition has 3 replicas. thanks!

Comment: This is because it doesn't add value to have multiple copies (replica) of the same data (partition) on one machine. Not from an availability perspective, nor from a performance perspective.